# For Notification : What is the difference between pendingIntent.cancel() and notificationManager.cancel(notification_id)

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

While doing the notification code, a doubt came in my mind. What is the difference between pendingIntent.cancel() and notificationManager.cancel(notification_id). I mean which one will clear the notification and what will the other one do?.

Comment: Everything is clearly define here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> which one will clear the notification

`cancel()` on `NotificationManager` will remove the `Notification`.

> what will the other one do?

It cancels the `PendingIntent`, so it no longer can be used.